# ERROR connecting: Connection refused

Tags: c, linux, sockets

IMPORTANT EDIT: After not changing anything it randomly started working. I have no idea why but thanks for all the help anyway!

I'm trying to learn how to create a client and a server that can interact with each other using C. I've done some research and followed a tutorial and I feel like I have a decent understanding of how it all works, but when I tried running the example the client cannot connect to the server.

Here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sockfd, portno, n;
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   struct hostent *server;

   char buffer[256];

   if (argc <3) {
      fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
   }
   portno = atoi(argv[2]);
   printf("PORT NUMBER: %d\n", portno);

   /* Create a socket point */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0)
   {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

   if (server == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
      exit(0);
   }

   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   /* Now connect to the server */
   if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
   {
      perror("ERROR connecting");
      exit(1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
   char buffer[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
   int  n;

   /* First call to socket() function */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("Successfully opened socket\n");

   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = 5771;

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR on binding");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("Successfully bound socket\n");

   /* Now start listening for the clients, here process will
   * go in sleep mode and will wait for the incoming connection
   */
   printf("Commence listening\n");
   listen(sockfd,50);
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

   /* Accept actual connection from the client */
   newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
   if (newsockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR on accept");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("CONNECTED.\n");

   return 0;
}
```

The output from the server is the following:

```
Successfully opened socket
Successfully bound socket
Commence Listening
```

I read some other questions asked here related to the connection refused error and they said that the most likely cause of the error was that the port wasn't open. But if my server is making it all the way to the listening step, shouldn't that mean that the port is in fact open? I don't think it has to do with passing in the wrong IP address to the client because I've tried passing in an incorrect IP address and it errors well before the connection refused.

Does anyone have any insight as to why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Are you using local IP (127.0.0.1) or public IP?

Comment: You have to use either 127.0.0.1 or the local IP assuming client and server are both behind the same router.

Comment: And not that it matters, but `clilen` should be type `socklen_t`, not `int`

Comment: I've tried both local and public.

Comment: What output do you get from the client?  Specifically, are you getting the correct port number?  Or, how are you invoking the client — what arguments are you giving it?

Comment: ./client 127.0.0.1 5771

The output looks like:
PORT NUMBER: 5771
ERROR connecting: Connection refused

Comment: Try the 'netstat -a' command on the server to see if the kernel thinks the port is active.  Try 'telnet' to the server and port to see if the server is responding.  If 'telnet' works then the problem is likely in the client.

Comment: With the server running, are you able to do "telnet localhost 5771"? What if you replace the server with "nc -l -p 5771"? You might have to check the syntax of nc in your distribution, different versions of nc take different arguments. If you are unable to connect with telnet to nc I would guess that you have some firewall blocking connections.

Comment: I was able to compile the code on Mac OS X 10.10.3 with minor mods (removed unused variables, such as argc and argv in server code, and buffer and n in both programs) — I called the programs `sv37` for the server and `cl37` for the client — and then ran: `./sv37` and `./cl37 localhost 5771` and it reported: `Successfully opened socket
Successfully bound socket
Commence listening
PORT NUMBER: 5771
CONNECTED.` which I take it is equivalent to being successful, and I got the same using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.  Do you have a firewall installed that blocks port 5771?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would assume not, I'm running it on my schools lab computers and it's part of a project they assigned.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist I also get a connection refused when trying to connect using telnet. Does this mean the port isn't actually being opened?

Comment: Annnnd it started working randomly. I didn't even change anything, weird.

Comment: use `tcpdump` to find out what happened

Comment: If telnet fails connecting to your server it means that the problem is not (only) in your client program. If telnet fails connecting to nc it means that the problem is not (only) in your server program, instead more likely some firewall setting.